# How to translate this piece of Java code to C#?

Tags: c#, java, enumerator

Here is the Java code which I want to translate to C#:

```
public Enumeration getLogHeaders()
{
return logHeaders != null ? logHeaders.elements() : null;
}
```

logHeaders is a `List<String>`.

This the translated C# version, but I get a compiler error whenever I try it.

```
public IEnumerable<string> getLogHeaders()
{
  return logHeaders != null ? logHeaders.GetEnumerator() : Enumerable.Empty<string>();
}
```

How would I have to change it?

Comment: GetEnumerator doesn't return an IEnumerable, it returns the enumerator itself. So remove that part and return logHeaders.

Comment: @harold: Could you post this as an answer, so Xris can accept it?

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I added the comment text to it, is that alright?

Comment: @harold Ah, I didn't see that this answer was already from you. Yes, the answer is better now, thanks. Xris, if harold's answer helped you, please accept it (use the checkmark button).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GetEnumerator doesn't return an IEnumerable, it returns the enumerator itself. So remove that part and return logHeaders.

Here's what I might write:

```
public IEnumerable<string> LogHeaders
{
   get { return logHeaders ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>(); }
}
```